# Use of USER in WHERE clause of a view in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, sql-view

I have been unable to find any information relevant to this question as it is rather specific. The situation is that I have created a view that is supposed to return results based on the user that calls it. The view is the following:

```
    CREATE VIEW V_ClientReward AS
    SELECT cl.id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM r1.recommendationDate) AS 
    yearRecommended,

    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Recommendation r2 
    WHERE r2.client1 = cl.id AND 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM r2.recommendationDate)= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
    r1.recommendationDate)
    AND r2.client2 IN(SELECT id FROM Client WHERE registrationDate IS NOT 
    NULL) GROUP BY r2.client1), 0) AS numberRecommendedContracted,

    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Recommendation r2 
    WHERE r2.client1 = cl.id AND 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM r2.recommendationDate)= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
    r1.recommendationDate)
    AND r2.client2 NOT IN(SELECT id FROM Client WHERE registrationDate IS 
    NOT NULL) GROUP BY r2.client1), 0) AS numberRecommendedNotContracted,

    ((SELECT rewardImport FROM ClientReward WHERE rewardYear = EXTRACT(YEAR 
    FROM r1.recommendationDate))*COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Recommendation r2 
    WHERE r2.client1 = cl.id AND 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM r2.recommendationDate)= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
    r1.recommendationDate)
    AND r2.client2 IN(SELECT id FROM Client WHERE registrationDate IS NOT 
    NULL)
    GROUP BY r2.client1), 0)) AS totalEarned 

    FROM Client cl INNER JOIN Recommendation r1
    ON cl.id=r1.client1
    INNER JOIN WebClient
    ON idUser = cl.id
    WHERE nick = USER
    GROUP BY cl.id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM r1.recommendationDate);
```

The idea being that after I have granted a user `SELECT` on this view, the simple act of calling it via `SELECT * FROM P18.V_ClientReward` should get the results based on that user's name. 
Unfortunately when I execute it I get no results at all, just empty fields. I have already attempted to execute the query specifying the user in question directly as `WHERE nick = 'user_name'` and it works perfectly.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is quite complicated and has too many underlying tables for us to reproduce your issue. For future reference you will be more likely to get quick help if you post a reproducible test case: in this case that would be a table, a view over that table and some sample data which demonstrates the problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables so I'm using one of my own.

First, the table contents: column NICK is used to distinguish database users (scott & hr). The table belongs to user SCOTT.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@xe
Connected.

SQL> select id_emp, fname, nick
  2  from person;

    ID_EMP FNAME                NICK
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 Little               HR
         2 Charles              HR
         3 Rio                  HR
         4 Seb                  SCOTT
         5 Romain               SCOTT
```

Creating a view, using `where` clause you used:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_person as
  2    select id_emp, fname
  3    from person
  4    where nick = user;

View created.
```

Grant privileges to user HR (otherwise, it won't see anything):

```
SQL> grant select on v_person to hr;

Grant succeeded.
```

---

OK, let's check what those users see.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> select * from v_person;

    ID_EMP FNAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Seb
         5 Romain

SQL> connect hr/hr@xe
Connected.

SQL> -- including the owner's name:
SQL> select * from scott.v_person;

    ID_EMP FNAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
         2 Charles
         3 Rio

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK, doesn't it?

As of your problem: did you, by any chance, use lowercase *nick* value?

```
SQL> update person set nick = 'scott' where id_emp > 3;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * From v_person;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

If not, could you create the same, simple example, which clearly shows what you did?

Comment: Hello there, I realise that it would have been useful to include tables but I thought it was something in my syntax and it would be easy to identify. It was indeed the upper/lowercase conflict. I have solved the issue with LOWER. Thanks so much for your detailed answer, it's excellent.